# Unable to retrieve the keycode of keyboard events on an Android device in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, events

**Title:**
event.keyCode not working on Android devices in JavaScript with editable `<div>`

**Description:**
I'm encountering an issue with the `event.keyCode` property not working as expected in JavaScript on Android devices, specifically within an editable `<div>`. I have an application that relies on capturing keyboard input, and I'm facing compatibility problems on Android devices specifically when using an editable `<div>`. Here are the details of my issue:

**Problem Description:**

- I have an HTML page with JavaScript that captures keyboard events within an editable `<div>`, and it works well on desktop and iOS browsers.
- However, on Android devices, the `event.keyCode` property does not provide the exact key code values for key presses or keydown or keyup or input within the editable `<div>`.

**Sample Code:**
Here is a simplified example of the code I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Editable DIV Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      id="editable-div"
      contenteditable="true"
      style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px"
    >
      Start typing here...
    </div>
    <div class="event-container">
      <div class="event-label">Keydown Event:</div>
      <div id="keydownValue" class="event-value" title="Keydown Event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-container">
      <div class="event-label">Keyup Event:</div>
      <div id="keyupValue" class="event-value" title="Keyup Event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-container">
      <div class="event-label">Keypress Event:</div>
      <div id="keypressValue" class="event-value" title="Keypress Event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-container">
      <div class="event-label">Input Event:</div>
      <div id="inputValue" class="event-value" title="Input Event"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      const editableDiv = document.getElementById('editable-div');
      const keydownValueDiv = document.getElementById('keydownValue');
      const keyupValueDiv = document.getElementById('keyupValue');
      const keypressValueDiv = document.getElementById('keypressValue');
      const inputValueDiv = document.getElementById('inputValue');

      editableDiv.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        const key = event.key; // Get the pressed key as a string
        const keyCode = event.code; // Get the key code

        // Update the keydownValueDiv content
        keydownValueDiv.textContent = 'Key: ' + key + ', KeyCode: ' + keyCode;
      });

      editableDiv.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
        const key = event.key; // Get the pressed key as a string
        const keyCode = event.code; // Get the key code

        // Update the keyupValueDiv content
        keyupValueDiv.textContent = 'Key: ' + key + ', KeyCode: ' + keyCode;
      });

      editableDiv.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
        const key = event.key; // Get the pressed key as a string
        const keyCode = event.keyCode; // Get the deprecated keyCode

        // Update the keypressValueDiv content
        keypressValueDiv.textContent = 'Key: ' + key + ', KeyCode: ' + keyCode;
      });

      editableDiv.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
        const key = event.key; // Get the pressed key as a string
        const keyCode = event.keyCode; // Get the deprecated keyCode

        // Update the inputValueDiv content
        inputValueDiv.textContent = 'Key: ' + key + ', KeyCode: ' + keyCode;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zqxbij?file=index.html

**Actual Behavior on Android:**

- On Android devices, within the editable `<div>`, the `event.keyCode` property does not work as expected, and it doesn't provide the key codes and it only provides 229 for all keys.

**Additional Information:**

- I've also attempted to use event.key and event.code as alternatives, but these properties are not working as expected on Android devices either. The issue persists, and I'm looking for a solution that works across a broader range of devices and browsers.

**Question:**

- Is there a reliable way to capture key codes on Android devices using JavaScript, considering the issues with `event.keyCode` on these devices, specifically within an editable `<div>`?

I would appreciate any insights or solutions to address this issue. Thank you in advance!

**Expected Behavior:**

- On Android browsers, this code should display the key code of the pressed key when typing inside the editable `<div>`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode very clearly states that this property is deprecated, and its use should be avoided if possible. It recommends using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code instead, if that is implemented on the target device already.